# Filling in holes and assigning values in vector (polygon) using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, filling, holes

I do have a vector which contained the field HazardClas (from 1- dark green to 5 - red) as you can seen in the figure below:

[image]

However, as you could see by visualizing the red arrows, there are some holes in the resulting polygon. What I would like to do is to find an efficient way to fill in the holes in the polygons and assign values (from 1 to 5) to each one of the them regarding the class that they belong to.

If I zoom in to an area I would like the final result to look like this (draft representation):

from
[image]

to (approximately)

[image]

I have already tried the Minimum Bounding Geometry and Envelope tools but they are not truly helpful to find a solution (at least to my understanding and knowledge).

How could I solve my problem using ArcMap?

Comment: If you wish to ask  about how to do this using ArcGIS Pro then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: I would try: Erase your minimum bounding with your data to get the holes as a new feature class, select by location all polygons except the outer bounding box, merge, eliminate. Do you have Advanced license?

Comment: Easy task, using Union with single input, no gaps. But you have to decide what to do if hole shares boundaries with 2 different classes.